# Permission denied error in php when try to write in a txt file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to write in a txt file the data i get from a html form, but I get this error: Warning: fopen(/var/www/4/datos.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/4/ComprobacionFormulario.php on line 13 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/4/ComprobacionFormulario.php on line 16 Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/4/ComprobacionFormulario.php on line 17

'datos.txt' Is the file where i'm trying to write. Here is my php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$des=$_POST['description'];
$cant=$_POST['quantity'];
$prec=$_POST['price'];
$nombrearchivo="datos.txt";
$content="Description: $des\tQuantity: $cant\tPrice: $prec\n";
$handle=fopen($nombrearchivo, 'w');

fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) [fopen] `Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.`

Looks like your `fopen` call is failing. Try using an absolute URL to your text file. Make sure your folder is CHMODded correctly and the file also (777 permissions)

Comment: I've tried to put "/var/www/4/$nombrearchivo" (it has 777 permissions), but still not working

Comment: does your folder `4` have those permissions too?